# recursively look for a specific directory in a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to create a batch file that will run as a build script.  I want to copy all dlls in any bin/debug directory from projects in my solution to a specific directory.   I'm just not sure how to determine if the directory ends with bin/debug in a for loop.

```
for /D /R "D:\mysolution\" %%F in ( *.* ) DO (
    rem if directory ends in "bin\debug"
    copy %%F\*.dll %1
)
```

Comment: In linux we can do `cp -r` you want to do the same in windows?

Comment: Simple: `for /R "D:\mysolution\" %%F in (bin\debug\*.dll) do copy "%%F" %1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `delayedexpansion` on this one, because we `set` a variable inside of a code block `( )`

Typically we just tell it that if the last 3 characters of the folder `= bin` or last 5 characters `= debug`, do something:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /D /R "D:\mysolution\" %%F in (*) DO (
   set "var=%%F"
   if /i "!var:~-3!"=="bin" copy "!var!\*.dll" %1
   if /i "!var:~-5!"=="debug" copy "!var!\*.dll" %1
)
```

This will copy all `dll`'s from directories named: `bin` `debug` `SOME dir NAME debug` `MYbin` etc. but not from `debug dir` `bin dir` etc.

**EDIT**

After your comment, this should do:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /D /R "D:\mysolution\" %%F in (*) DO (
   set "var=%%F"
   if /i "!var:~-9!"=="bin\debug" copy "!var!\*.dll" %1
)
```

Comment: @michael_heath : OP's question is not particularly clear. Since he appears to use the backslash correctly in his posted code, I believe it's possible that the `/` here means "or", but It may be that the requirement is `bin\debug` as you conclude.

Comment: If that is the case, I will update my answer. Thank you.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard - sorry, that was a typo it should have been "bin\debug"

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=m:\tokyo"
SET "destdir=u:\destdir"

FOR /r "%sourcedir%" %%a IN (*.dll) DO (
 FOR %%t IN ("%%~dpa.") DO (
  IF /i "%%~nxt" == "bin64" ECHO(copy "%%a" "%destdir%"
  IF /i "%%~nxt" == "bin" ECHO(copy "%%a" "%destdir%"
 )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances.

The required COPY commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(COPY` to `COPY` to actually copy the files. Append `>nul` to suppress report messages (eg. `1 file copied`)

I chose to select the `.dll` files from my `M:\tokyo...\bin64` and `M:\tokyo...\bin` directories for ease of testing.

Use `for/r` to locate all of the `.dll` files starting at the nominated directory, assigning each in turn to `%%a`.

Assign the literal (drive+path)from %%a +`.` to `%%t`, yielding the immediate parent directoryname as the "filename" and compare with case-INsensitivity (`/i`) the "filename" to each desired string in turn. This ensures that the *entire* parent-directoryname is compared, so we don't have false hits on a name like `not_this_directory_even_though_its_a_bin`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use another [`for` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html) together with [`~` modifiers](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) to determine the name of the parent directory too, then let us check against the partial path `bin\debug`:

```cmd
for /D /R "D:\mysolution\" %%J in ("*") do (
    for %%I in ("%%~dpJ.") do (
        if /I "%%~nxI\%%~nxJ"=="bin\debug" (
            copy "%%~J\*.dll" "%~1"
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your now verified intent, i.e. trees ending `\bin\debug`, this prefilters the directory recursion results, then verifies the name before running the `Copy` command:

```bat
@Echo Off
If "%~1"=="" (Exit /B) Else CD /D "%~1" 2>Nul && (Set "CP=Copy /Y "%%A\*.dll" 2>Nul") || Exit /B
For /D /R "D:\mysolution" %%A In (bin\d?bug) Do For %%B In ("%%~nxA.") Do If /I "%%~nB"=="debug" %CP%
```

*This should only work if your input arg[0], `%1`, is provided and exists.*